# How to loop through a form and add same form in django if we click add more button and store that in django

Tags: python, django, forms, orm, model

What I really want to do is , if a user click on "ADD more" button then a same form repeat itself and the values should store in database, if he/she doesn't click of that button then only the values from first form should be stored.

I am not able to get this, I just created a form , and a table in database for those details but can't loop though the form neither in data.

please help.

[This is the form and the button:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvQTW.png)

> This is the model.py code:

```
from django.db import models

class experience(models.Model):
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    startdate = models.Datefield(default = 01-01-2020)
    lastdate = models.DateField(default = 01-01-2020)
    profile = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(max_length = 250)
```

> This is the views.py code:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
import requests
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, auth


# Create your views here.
def profile(request):

    return render(request, 'profile.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there's no built-in way (as far as I know) in Django to do that without Javascript, but here's an approach:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container" id="experiencesContainer">
  <form method='POST' name='experienceForm'>
    {{form.as_p}}
    </form>
   <form method='POST' name='experienceForm'>
    {{form.as_p}}
    </form>
  <button type="button" id="addMoreButton">Add more</button>
  <button type="submit">Save Changes</button>
</div>
```

**Django POST method:**

```
# Get a list of submitted forms
experiences = request.POST.getlist('experienceForm')
for experience in experiences:
    # this is how you loop throuh every form
    experience.get('company_name)
```

**Your javascript something like:**

```
// clonning his childs as well
let cloneForm = document.querySelector('form[name=experienceForm]').cloneNode(true);
document.querySelector('div#experiencesContainer').appendChild(cloneForm);
// see this https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_clonenode.asp
```

Of course this code is not tested but I've done this in several projects before, hope it works!

Answer (score 0):

A simple way would be to request the same view from the "Add", just make sure your form view saves the data when request method is POST.

```
<form action="{% url 'your-form-url' %}" method="GET">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="submit" value="Add">
</form>
```

one other way to repeat forms would be using [formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/formsets/). Formsets allow you to repeat the same form 'extra' times. *Check out the documentation for more about this.*

```
def repeat_form(request):
    ExpFormSet = formset_factory(ExperienceForm, extra=3)
    #extra defines the no. of forms you want to display
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = ExpFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if formset.is_valid():
            # do something with the formset.cleaned_data
            #loop through each form in the formser
            for form in formset.cleaned_data:
                obj = form.save()

    else:
        formset = ExpFormSet()
    return render(request, 'exp_form.html', {'formset': formset})
```

The corresponding template should be:-

```
<form method="post">
    {{ formset.management_form }}
        {% for form in formset %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        {% endfor %}
</form>
```

Make sure you add form.management_form. Using the combination of the above might solve your problem of taking and saving several inputs.